# Vim function calling system() returns unwanted escape characters in iTerm2

Tags: vim, iterm2

I have this function in my .vimrc:

```
function! GitBranch()
  return system("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n'")
endfunction
```

But it's adding this sequence of characters: `^[[?12;4$y` to the bottom of my screen.

This only happens in iTerm2 (it doesn't happen on the default terminal on my mac), and happens regardless of the system call. Even if I replace the above system call with `system("echo test")` I still get the same sequence showing up.

What could be causing this and how do I get it to stop?

I'm using zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0), `$TERM` is xterm-256color, vim version is

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Dec 16 2022 23:29:16)
macOS version - arm64
Included patches: 1-981
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
-arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
-balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        -vartabs
+clipboard         -keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            -profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      -langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          -rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
-emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

Comment: If it happens with any external command, then there is no point mentioning your status line efforts. What you should have mentioned, though, is your shell and its version, your `$TERM`, the full output of `$ vim --version`, and whether the behavior is still present without your Vim config: `$ vim -Nu NONE`. FWIW I can't reproduce the problem in the latest iTerm, Vim 9.0.1276, and latest bash.

Comment: Apologies, I'll add that!

Comment: Thanks. How about `$ vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: Version 9.0.981

Comment: You already provided the version. I'm asking you to try `system()` again *without your config*.

Comment: Oh my bad! Without the config there isn't an issue. Even if I keep the config but remove the line that uses this function, I don't get an error.